# Show that the inverse function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse-function, fake-proofs

> Let be $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous, bijective function and $I$ an intervall of $\mathbb{R}$. Further, let be $g:J\to I$ the inverse function of $f$ such that for all $y\in J$ we have $f(g(y))=y$ and for all $x\in I$ we have $g(f(x))=x$.
>
> Show that $g$ is continuous.

---

Let be $\epsilon>0$ and $a\in I$ (both arbitrarily chosen). As $f$ is continuous there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in I$ with $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

It follows from the properties of the inverse function $g$ that for $a\in I$ there exists a unique $b\in J$ and for each $x\in I$ a unique $y\in J$ such that $|x-a|=|g(y)-g(b)|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|=|y-b|<\epsilon$. As $f$ is bijective this implication also holds reversely.

So if I take another arbitrary $\epsilon'>0$ and shrink (if necessary) $\delta$ such that $0<\delta<\epsilon'$ then it holds that for all $y\in J$ with $|y-b|<\epsilon\implies |g(y)-g(b)|<\delta<\epsilon'$ which shows the continuity of the inverse function $g$.

---

I know that there are already numerous proofs on this issue which use strict monotonicity (also the one in my lecture notes). However, as my approach is so short I have the feeling that it is wrong and that I have overlooked something. Where is it flawed?

Comment: "As f is bijective this implication also holds reversely." -- This is what you need to prove, both in the implication and in the order of selection of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$

Comment: +1: Independent of the validity of your work, with respect to the comment of Brian Moehring -- excellent use of MathJax to present the query and your work, and excellent effort showing your work and thoughts on the subject.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I thought that this is exactly what I did in the last part "So if I take another [...]", isn't it?

Comment: @Philipp No, you [incorrectly] apply it in the last part.  You never proved it.  More directly, if $$|g(y)-g(b)| < \delta \implies |y-b| < \epsilon$$ is true, why would $$|y-b| < \epsilon \implies |g(y)-g(b)| < \delta$$ be true? (it's not true, even for continuous, bijective functions -- give it a try with any function $g$ that isn't locally linear around $b$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring, how is "locally linear" defined?

Comment: "Locally" just means "within a small enough open interval" (or more generally, "within some open set").  It occurs to me that this isn't sufficient to avoid weird cases, so we can just ignore it.  My point is that $$|g(y)-g(b)| < \delta \iff |y-b| < \epsilon,$$ which is seemingly what you are using, only can hold when $2g(b) = g(b-\epsilon) + g(b+\epsilon)$ and this doesn't follow from your assumptions.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I am not sure if I've understood you argument correctly but I presume that it points at the following: if there exists a $y'\in J$ with $|y'-b|<\epsilon\implies |g(y')-g(b)|\geq\delta$ it means that $f$ would no longer map bijectively between a $\delta$-neighbourhood $N_{\delta}(g(b))$ and a $\epsilon$-neighbourhood $N_{\epsilon}(b)$ because $y'$ has no preimage that lies in $N_{\delta}(g(b))$.

Comment: So being "globally" bijective doesn't mean automatically that $f$ is also locally bijecitve. However, if I can show this claim it would be legit to use the equivalence you mentioned in you last comment. Is this idea correct?